# Memory leaks class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

Im receiving a bunch of memory leaks from the code below...Ive tried to rewrite it in a better way but really can't think of anything else. Suggestions would be appreciated. Below is the the object that the message is sent to.

```
Packet *packet;
packet = [PacketAudioBuffer packetWithData:data];
```

**PacketAudioBuffer.m file ->**

```
+ (id)packetWithData:(NSData *)data
{
   int totalSize = [data length];

   int packetNumber = [data pm_int32AtOffset:4];

   return [[self alloc] initWithAudioBufferData:data totalSize:totalSize packetNumber:packetNumber];
}

- (id)initWithAudioBufferData:(NSData *)data
                totalSize:(UInt32)totalSize
           packetNumber:(UInt32)packetNumber
{

if ((self = [super initWithType:PacketTypeAudioBuffer]))
{
       // this is where audioBufferData is set.
       self.audioBufferData = data;
       self.totalSize = totalSize;
       self.packetNumber = packetNumber;
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Whatever calls packetWithData is responsible for releasing the result.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this  . . .

```
+ (id)packetWithData:(NSData *)data
{
   int totalSize = [data length];

   int packetNumber = [data pm_int32AtOffset:4];

   return [[[self alloc] initWithAudioBufferData:data totalSize:totalSize packetNumber:packetNumber] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not using ARC, so returning the result of `alloc` from a method that isn't new, alloc, retain or copy without autoreleasing it is incorrect. Add an autoreleased to the return statement of `packetWithData:`.

Also, I'd recommend reading the memory management guide. It isn't long, and this stuff is really fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the class method you implemented. Try to simplify like this:

```
- (id)initWithAudioBufferData:(NSData *)data
{

    if ((self = [super initWithType:PacketTypeAudioBuffer]))
    {
        // this is where audioBufferData is set.
        self.audioBufferData = data;
        self.totalSize = [data length];
        self.packetNumber = [data pm_int32AtOffset:4];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
PacketAudioBuffer *packet = [[PacketAudioBuffer alloc] initWithAudioBufferData:data];
```

Hope this helps.